# Fatal error: Call to undefined function msqli_real_escape_string() in C:\xampp\htdocs\php-get-started\updateData.php on line 48

Tags: php

I am trying to update a record in my database using a form and php, but I keep receiving the following error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function msqli_real_escape_string() in C:\xampp\htdocs\php-get-started\updateData.php on line 48

I cannot see anything that I may have missed out in the code. I am running XAMPP and using PHP version 5.6.8. Can anyone help?

Thanks in anticipation.

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_GET['id']) && ctype_digit($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
    } else {
        header('Location: select.php');
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PHP Update Data</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
  $name = '';
  $gender = '';
  $color = '';
  $email = '';

  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $ok = true;
    if (!isset($_POST['name']) || $_POST['name'] === '') {
        $ok = false;
    } else {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
    }
    if (!isset($_POST['gender']) || $_POST['gender'] === '') {
        $ok = false;
    } else {
        $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    }
    if (!isset($_POST['color']) || $_POST['color'] === '') {
        $ok = false;
    } else {
        $color = $_POST['color'];
    }
    if (!isset($_POST['email']) || $_POST['email'] === '') {
        $ok = false;
    } else {
        $name = $_POST['email'];
    }

    if ($ok) {
        // add database code here
        $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'php');
        $sql = sprintf("UPDATE users SET name='%s', gender='%s', color='%s', email='%s'
            WHERE id=%s",
            msqli_real_escape_string($db, $name),
            msqli_real_escape_string($db, $gender),
            msqli_real_escape_string($db, $color),
            msqli_real_escape_string($db, $email),
            $id);
            mysqli_query($db, $sql);
            echo '<p>User updated</p>';
            mysqli_close($db);
    }
  } else {
      $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'php');
      $sql = sprintf('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=%s', $id);
      $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
      foreach ($result as $row) {
          $name = $row['name'];
          $gender = $row['gender'];
          $color = $row['color'];
          $email = $row['email'];
      }
      mysqli_close($db);
  }
?>
<form method="post" action="">
    User name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php
        echo htmlspecialchars($name);
    ?>"><br>
    Gender:
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="f"<?php
            if ($gender === 'f') {
                echo ' checked';
            }
        ?>>female
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="m"<?php
            if ($gender === 'm') {
                echo ' checked';
            }
        ?>>male<br>
    Favorite color:
        <select name="color">
            <option value="">Please select</option>
            <option value="#f00"<?php
                if ($color === '#f00') {
                    echo ' selected';
                }
            ?>>red</option>
            <option value="#0f0"<?php
                if ($color === '#0f0') {
                    echo ' selected';
                }
            ?>>green</option>
            <option value="#00f"<?php
                if ($color === '#00f') {
                    echo ' selected';
                }
            ?>>blue</option>
        </select><br>
    Email: <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php
        echo htmlspecialchars($email);
    ?>"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This code could do with a serious cleanup. What is the content of line 48?

Comment: Did you do any research yourself to figure out what the problem is? I doubt it would take more than a few seconds.

Comment: I did lots of research before I posed the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it is             `m**y**sqli_real_escape_string($db, $name),`
 **NOT**  msqli_real_escape_string($db, $name),

Comment: It's best to not answer questions that could be solved with a Google search. It just encourages more of the same to come.

Comment: It is actually a typo error only!!!

Comment: Well spotted Sajad. I am an idiot! Cheers.